# Bash conceptual questions

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux & bash, and I am working on some different scripts, but I have a few conceptual questions I need answered to help me find the best approach to what I want to do.

1. What is the most efficient way to store data in a bash script, and save it as a file, that another script can speedily parse?
2. What are some good examples of colorful bash menu's? How can I have a multi-column menu's in bash?
3. Can I display images in bash or would it be better to send the image info to, let's say a notify-send, and have it to display any images?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have better luck with specific questions that generally (but not always) should involve a specific piece of code.

Comment: This is way too open ended. `1` is dependent on your data and how you use it, `2` is a list-of-stuff question, `3` doesn't say what you're actually trying to do (XY problem). Voting to close as NARQ

Comment: Look into [`whiptail`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) or [`dialog`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2460).

Comment: I am trying to learn bash, and learn best ways to solve application problems. I am trying to create a bash script that stores movie metadata, such as: Title, Year, Genre, Directors, Etc....Knowing what method of storing can be useful for this and any future apps I create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite a potpourri of questions :-)

Firstly, the most efficient way to store data in a `bash` script depends *entirely* on the data and the processing you want done to it. If the processing will be done by `bash` itself, it'll probably be faster in a `bash` variable (size permitting). If external programs like `grep`, `sed` or `awk` will be processing it under the direction of `bash`, a file may be better.

But that's a *very* general guideline - you need to analyse both the data and the use of it, especially since *how* it's stored in the file is also important. By way of example, I wouldn't store fixed length records as an XML file if I was processing it in `bash` alone, since that means I'd have to write a whole lot of XML processing code for the shell. I'd probably just store it as fixed length records in a flat file.

Secondly, I have no examples for you, as `bash` tends to either be a command-line driven thing or, at most, a very simple menu-based thing. It's not generally used for fancy UI work.

And you can quite easily have multi-column menus, the simplest form being something like:

```
echo "1. Enter new contact.       4. Find contact"
echo "2. Edit contact             5. Exit"
echo "3. Delete contact"
```

Lastly, `bash` itself has no support for displaying images any more complicated than ASCII art:

```
  |\_/|
 / @ @ \
( > º < )
 \__V__/
 /  O  \
```

So, if you need something more complex than that, you'll probably be passing it off to an external program.

Comment: +1 for cat(?). I didn't even read your ans :D

Comment: Hey! That's a picture of my wife, you insensitive clod :-) Oh well, such are the inaccuracies of ASCII art.

Comment: Now I know why you spend so much time on SO :P

Comment: Nice cat :), I need to store data, that different bash scripts may need to access, what are good ways to store data that may have special characters in it?